# How old was St. Joseph when he married the Blessed Virgin Mary?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, church-fathers, joseph

According to the Church Fathers or other Catholic theologians, how old was St. Joseph when he married the Blessed Virgin Mary?

Comment: On behalf of the Orthodox, I feel I  should ask, 'Which time?'

Comment: @bradimus The Orthodox think he was married more than once‽

Comment: Yes (maybe). The Orthodox usually assert that Joseph was a widower before being betrothed to Mary. James and Jesus's other brothers are half-brothers from this first marriage. (I said maybe because I'm not sure if the Orthodox say that Joseph and Mary were married or only betrothed.)

Comment: @bradimus [That's actually a Catholic belief as well](https://www.catholic.com/index.php/qa/was-st-joseph-a-virgin-or-a-widower-with-children).

Comment: Neither Orthodox or Catholic believe Mary/Joseph consummated their marriage.  Nor did Aquinas think so, but expressly says did not consummate.

Comment: @Geremia [obligatory reference for perpetual betrothal](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/online-edition/when-were-joseph-and-mary-married)

Comment: @bradimus The Orthodox wiki has a page "[Joseph the Betrothed](https://orthodoxwiki.org/Joseph_the_Betrothed)." I wonder why they think he wasn't really married to the Blessed Virgin. According to Catholicism (cf. [_Summa Theologica_ III q. 29 a. 2](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP029.html#TPQ29A2THEP1)), they had a true marriage.

Comment: I am not sure. Most of the Orthodox beliefs on the matter seem to line up with the Protoevangelium of James, but I don't think betrothal vs marriage is addressed there.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer See: "[Was St. Joseph Previously Married?](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/view.cfm?recnum=9298)" by Phillip Bellini.

Comment: @Geremia The understanding on both parties' sides here is the same.  Only the particular emphasis is different.  Both parties agree no sex occurred (i.e. the marriage was not 'consummated' in the usual sense), but also that the marriage was lacking nothing proper to a 'real' marriage-- it had no less value and the Holy Family was a proper family unit.  St Joseph the Perpetually Betrothed as a title pays homage to the chastity between Mary and Joseph while Aquinas's piece is in objection to the idea that their marriage was in some way incomplete or lesser merely because there was no sex.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer But what about the question of the title of the article: "Was St. Joseph Previously Married?"

Comment: @Geremia I meant regarding the virginity of Mary, the validity of her marriage to Joseph, and the validity of the Holy Family.

Comment: @Geremia ." I wonder why they think he wasn't really married to the Blessed Virgin. According to Catholicism"

They do, but its how the words are used.  Betrothal was the first "half" of getting married, the final part was consummation.  So it was not a consummated marriage, so it's referred to as a betrothal to avoid confusion that it may have been a consummated marriage.

Comment: @JosephHirsch An unconsummated marriage is still a marriage.

Comment: @Geremia in Orthodoxy betrothal is considered marriage,  so saying Joseph was betrothed means they were married but may have been used to confirm it wasn’t consummated.  Betrothal and consummation are actually viewed by Orthodox as two sacraments, but we usually just talk about marriage as one to talk consistently with Catholics

Comment: @JosephHirsch The Old Testament Hebrews' betrothals ≠ [Christians' betrothal ("a promise of a future marriage")](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/XP/XP043.html#XPQ43A1THEP1). The former "[was equivalent to our \[Christians'\] valid but not consummated marriage.](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9015)"

Comment: @geremia What is your point.  Betrothal is the first sacrament of marriage in the Orthodox Church.  The Orthodox Church doesn't limit the sacraments to 7, but confirms that there are at least 7.  Once betrothed in Orthodoxy you are married.  Also an unconsummated marriage in the Roman Catholic Church is almost always annulled if one of the parties desires, and that means it was never a marriage in the West.  You asked a question. In Orthodoxy to say Joseph was betrothed means he was married, but without implying consummation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to ch. 1 of [*The Divine Favors Granted to St. Joseph*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/6472) (1973) by Père Binet, S.J., the general opinion among theologians is that St. Joseph was, when he married, "neither an old man nor a youth, but in the prime of life, between thirty and forty":

> A secret inspiration from heaven caused both Mary and Joseph to contract this alliance, while adoring in their hearts the impenetrable counsel of the great God. Mary was in her fifteenth year; the age of Joseph is not known so exactly, tradition being silent on the subject. The opinion that he was about eighty years old is without reasonable grounds, and is not held by theologians, the most esteemed of whom think that he was neither an old man nor a youth, but in the prime of life, between thirty and forty. There are many reasons in support of this opinion, which is now generally held.

---

The first treatise on St. Joseph, the 1522 [*Summa de donis de S. Joseph*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=8372) by Isidore de Isolanis, O.P. (pp. 81-88, PDF pp. 110-17), advances several arguments:

#### in favor of a young St. Joseph

1. Spouses were roughly the same age. St. Mary was younger. ∴, St. Joseph was young.
2. St. Mary couldn't be thought to be St. Joseph's daughter.
3. St. Joseph needed to be young and healthy to protect St. Mary and Jesus, travel to different regions, and work for them.
4. The prophecy Isaiah 62:5: "For the young man [St. Joseph] shall dwell with the virgin [St. Mary]"

#### opposed to a young St. Joseph

1. He was middle-aged, but old enough to be manly and knowledgeable of Holy Scriptures.
2. He must have been old enough to have acquired a grave demeanor, prudence, and fortitude.
3. He stayed 7 years in Egypt. The Egyptians hated the Israelites, so he must have been old enough to defend against this.

Comment: If the Isaac/Rebekah pattern continued, Isaac was about 40, which implies Joseph about 40 (Gen. 25:20).  However, they lived into 100 age.

Answer (score 2):

Among the Church Fathers, the earliest answer with any precision is Epiphanius (4th century), who said in [*Panarion* 78.8](https://books.google.com/books?id=W_cFEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA606):

> Joseph begot James when he was somewhere around forty years old. After him he had a son named Joses—then Simeon after him, then Judah, and two daughters, one named Mary and one, Salome; and his wife died. And many years later, as a widower of over eighty, he took Mary.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of the "old Joseph" and "young Mary" is in the Infancy Gospel of James, per Origen.  Scripture *implies* they would have been about a similar age.

Some 200 years later, Jerome was aghast at the idea that Joseph wasn't also understood to be an ever-virgin.  He then invented the cousin theory to explain the nature of the brothers and sisters of Jesus.  Cousins, rather than children of old Joseph from a previous marriage when he was younger.

So, to answer the OP question, the answer about ages will depend upon your source.  Scripture (implies about same age), Infancy Gospel (old Joseph, young Mary), Jerome (unclear, though probably about same age, but no consummated marriage).  To be sure, there are many others (Origen, Valentinus, Tertullian, Clement of Alexandria, Cyril of Jerusalem, Hegesippius, and others) who opined about this issue.

[Infancy Gospel of James](http://www.earlychristianwritings.com/infancyjames.html)

> book of James reference 5265 below

[The Brethren of Jesus --- Origen](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf09.xvi.ii.iii.xvii.html)

> And they [home town folk] spoke, wondering, (not knowing that He was the son of a virgin, or not believing it even if it was told to them, but supposing that He was the son of Joseph the carpenter,) “is not this the carpenter’s son?”5262  And depreciating the whole of what appeared to be His nearest kindred, they said, “Is not His mother called Mary?  And His brethren, James and Joseph and Simon and Judas?  And His sisters, are they not all with us?”5263  **They thought, then, that He was the son of Joseph and Mary.  But some say, basing it on a tradition in the Gospel according to Peter,5264 as it is entitled, or “The Book of James,”5265 that the brethren of Jesus were sons of Joseph by a former wife, whom he married before Mary.**  Now those who say so wish to preserve the honour of Mary in virginity to the end, so that that body of hers which was appointed to minister to the Word which said, “The Holy Ghost shall come upon thee, and the power of the Most High shall overshadow thee,”5266 might not know intercourse with a man after that the Holy Ghost came into her and the power from on high overshadowed her.  And I think it in harmony with reason that Jesus was the first-fruit among men of the purity which consists in chastity, and Mary among women; for it were not pious to ascribe to any other than to her the first-fruit of virginity.

Comment: The gospel of James hardly counts as a writing of "the Church Fathers or other Catholic Theologians".  Also, Origen says that the Gospel of James is echoing an earlier, also-dubious Gospel of Peter with the claim regarding Joseph's previous marriage, though the assertion that either work was the *source* of the belief seems unlikely to be correct.

Comment: "Scripture (same age)" is not the teaching of Scripture.

Comment: Origen "basing it on a tradition" from GoP or Infancy Gospel of James; that's the source (not scripture).  IOW, Origen does not say basing it on a tradition from some source (like an apostle or scripture) prior to Infancy Gospel that is written.

Comment: Scripture (same age) is what is taught.  IOW, at that time, there was the idea of a same age couple (scripture) OR there was the idea from Infancy Gospel of old Joseph/young Mary.  Take a pick per your source.  As well, "Church Fathers" depends on your belief, rather than on some well established catholic holy orthodox definition.

Comment: Are you referring to St. Jerome's [_The Perpetual Virginity of Blessed Mary_](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/3007.htm)?

Comment: Can you provide book, chapter and verse of the bible where Scripture states they would have been of a similar age?

Comment: "Similar age", when Christ ministered in His early 30's in His hometown, the crowd asked isn't this the carpenter's son and his mother Mary (Mt. 13:55).  This implies "similar age" or both still alive with Joseph still at carpentry work.  Jesus had at least 4 brothers and 2 sisters, which also implies "similar age" (Mt. 13:55-56).  This is Origen's Scripture reference.  OR, as Origen says, one can believe the tradition from the Infancy Gospel about "old Joseph" and "young Mary" and disagree about "similar age".

Comment: SLM that does not imply anything about the age of Joseph. It doesn't even prove he was still alive or working. It only proves that the people knew who he was and considering that his home town was likely populated by no more than 200 people, Joseph could have been dead for years and people would still know who he was. The reality is that the scripture tells us nothing about the age of Joseph.

Comment: @SLM Probably you should have used the word "imply" and not "state" which [means](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/state) "_to say or write something, especially clearly and carefully"_. And I think you could put references of what you wrote.

Comment: Can you add a citation or quotation for Origen?